# microsoft.sharepoint.client.site class/namespace/dll missing maybe

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

I'm using VS 2010 on Windows XP.
I did download microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll & microsoft.sharepoint.client.Runtime.dll from Microsoft Client Object model on my computer.

I was able to find above dll's in 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client,
Not at below location.
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI -- as pointed on some other articles and stackoverflow question.

Task: SSIS & SharePoint Integration and download files from SharePoint site (SP 2010).

Here is the problem.
I'm trying to use namespace SPSite and SPWebsite but VS 2010 doesn't recognize. 
I have add above mentioned dlls as reference and my target framework 4.0.

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl)) --Error: The type or namespace SpSite couldn't be found (are you missing using directive or assembly reference).

1. Is above error something to do with .dll's installed on different location.
2. I have 32 bit software(64 bit OS) 
   so when downloading Microsoft Sharepoint dll's i had to select (X86).
3. Also when downloading Microsoft Sharepoint dll's, system requirement: Windows 7, Window Server 2008 and so on but didn't see Windows XP.

Tell me what i'm missing or did i do anything wrong here.
Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!!

Comment: How did you get the DLLs? Was it from this link? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786

Comment: Yes. Exactly same link. Check out System Requirements from the link. I gut feeling is, it's not working because of Windows XP OS but i'm a newbie so need confirmation and also if there is any workaround. let me know.

Comment: You need to decide if you need "client side object model(OM)" (to run on a machine that is able to navigate to SharePoint site via browsers) or "server side OM" (runs only on server machine that hosts SharePoint site itself). Your download is for client side OM, but likely samples you are looking for are server side OM.

Comment: Alexei, oh i miss that. So you think i need to install something on Server side as well but then what should be reference in VS 2010, it has to be the one of my machine where VS 2010 exists correct.

Comment: Two classes which you named (SPSite, SPWeb) are part of Server Object Model which is available only on SharePoint server. 
But you imported Client Object Model which has another classes to access SharePoint. Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response,Yevgeniy. OK, i have been thru the article. I understand i need to install something on Sharepoint server. 1. Let me know what do i need to install on server. 2.How do i access the objects in my application. Again i'm a newbie so i need little more help. Only help i need is, how to access SPSite and SPWeb and things i have to do in order to access SPSite and SPWeb. Thanks again!!